# Replace multiple dots and comma javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `number_format($number,2,",",".")`. An example number is in this format: `8.726,36`

I did sum of rows with javascript:

```
var totals = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");
    $dataRows.each(function() {
        $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i) {        
            totals[i] += parseFloat( $(this).html());
        });
    });

    $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i) {  
        $(this).html(totals[i].toFixed(2).replace(".",",")+ " kn");
    });
});
```

But total is not good (blue row).

[image: Photo]

How can I use multiple `.replace(",",".")`?

Comment: `.replace(/,/g,'.');`?

Comment: You clearly know that JavaScript always uses `.` for decimal, and you clearly know how to replace characters, so what's the question? Your `totals[i] += parseFloat( $(this).html());` line ignores JS's number format and feeds it values like `8.726,36` expecting it to realize that's a number in the thousands. It won't magically do that, *you* have to do it, the same way you did the converse when displaying at the end.

Comment: Is your question how you should use . instead of , as a thousands separator? This has to do with localisation. Does this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing numbers in and out of human-readable format is a terrible idea. What if one day your team decides to use a different format, like `1'234'567.89`? You're stuffed!

Instead, generate something like:

```
<span class="number" data-value="1234567.89">1.234.567,89</span>
```

That way you can access `.data('value')` to get the actual value of the number, consistently, without worry for the future.

Comment: And I'm telling you you're doing it fundamentally wrong.